# Apple Beta Review Process

Tags: ios, app-store, review

I want to distribute my app to 100 people before I open it for the public. So I'm planning to submit my app for the beta review process and there are some buttons in the application which are still not functional.

We are in Beta and it's very important for those 100 people to see that those features are in the bucket list. So my questions is if I place those buttons in the screen and submit for beta review, will Apple reject my application ?

I know they will reject if I submit for App store but will they do the same for Beta review ?

Cheers

Comment: Your question only matters if you are using Apple's TestFlight service.  If you want to distribute to 100 people or less, [you can use ADHOC (as described here)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) (and no review) to distribute.

Comment: With TestFlight service in iTunes Connect, you can add up to 100 External Testers as opposed to Internal Testers which are declared users of your iTunes Connect account. Each submission to beta test will allow you to start tests by send an email to these testers. Apple won't reject your beta submission but asks each time if your app encrypts data (may be for future rejection ;) ?)

Comment: The testers you are asking about get it before Apple even has a chance to reject it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is it about Apple's app submission process.  Stack Overflow is not Apple Customer Support.

Answer (score 2):

Apple will not care about that button, while you're in beta process, but you should add a Note under Beta Review Information and tell them about your buttons. But when you're sending for Review process for App Store, they will reject. Hope it's helps.